# How to have a formsubmit.co form not redirect while also disabling the submit button for 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I am making a javascript that upon submitting a formsubmit.co form submits the form without redirecting. I then want the submit button to be disabled and count down 60 seconds. After 60 seconds, the button will be enabled again. However, the button currently only sends the form without disabling the button and counting down the time.

I attempted making an if statement under submitForm() where the function that disables the button only activates once the HTML for the button changes to "Submitted". My idea was that if Javascript runs in order, it will ensure the form is submitted and then disable the button. However, this did not fix the problem.

Note: the timer is set to 10s for editing purposes and will be changed again later.

My code is as follows:

```
<div style="background-color: #0e1b4d; padding-left: 10%; padding-right: 10%;">
<form method="POST" class="my-form" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
     <label>Full Name <sup style="color: red; font-size: 13px;">*</sup></label><br>
     <input class="freeEntryInput" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required><br>
     <label>Email Address <sup style="color: red; font-size: 13px">*</sup></label><br>
     <input class="freeEntryInput" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required><br>
     <label style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;"><input type="checkbox" name="contest rules" required>  I have read and agree to the <span class="contestRulesLink">Contest Rules</span></label>
     <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
     <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display:none">
     <button id="freeEntryButton" onclick="hideFreeEntryButton" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
</div>
<script> 
function submitForm() {
    const form = document.querySelector('.my-form')
    const formData = new FormData(form)
    const url = 'https://formsubmit.co/<email>'
    fetch(
      url,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      }
    )
    return false;
    document.getElementById('freeEntryButton').innerHTML = "Submitted";
    if (document.getElementById('freeEntryButton').innerHTML == "Submitted") {
        function hideFreeEntryButton() { 
            document.getElementById('freeEntryButton').disabled = true; 
            var secs = 10;
            var countdown = setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById('freeEntryButton').innerHTML = secs + "s remains";
                secs--;
                if (secs < 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
                    document.getElementById('freeEntryButton').disabled = false;   
                    document.getElementById('freeEntryButton').innerHTML = "Submit Form"; 
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `Submitted` variable defined?

Comment: I noticed I forgot to make Submitted a string. That's updated in the code now.

Comment: You have to put the line ```return false;``` at the end of the function. Code after return will not be executed.

Comment: That solved it. As well, I moved my function to a global function and just called it in the if statement.